# How can i use requests to achieve the same as this curl script, but in python?

Tags: python-3.x, curl

I am trying to work with Nuance speech API, i have successfully managed to use other APIs in the past but most of the time they are more straight forward than this. And for whatever reason, the Python code i'm using to make requests doesn't seem to be doing the job.

Here's the curl script i'm trying to replicate.

```
curl "https://dictation.nuancemobility.net:443/NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation?appId=[APP_ID]&appKey=[APP_KEY]&id=[ID]" -H "Content-Type: audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000" -H "Accept-Language: ENUS" -H "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Accept-Topic: Dictation" -k --data-binary @audio_16k16bit.pcm  -v
```

This is how i am trying to send the data in python.

```
import requests

url = 'https://dictation.nuancemobility.net:443/NMDPAsrCmdServlet/dictation?appId=[APP_ID]&appKey=[APP_KEY]&id=[ID]'
headers = {}
headers['Content-Type'] = 'audio/x-wav;codec=pcm;bit=16;rate=16000'
headers['Accept-Language'] = 'ENUS'
headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'
headers['Accept'] = 'application/xml'
headers['Accept-Topic'] = 'Dictation'
data = open('audio_16k16bit.pcm', 'rb')
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
```

Here is also a copy of the [documentation](https://developer.nuance.com//public/Help/HttpInterface/HTTP_web_services_for_NCS_clients_1.0_programmer_s_guide.pdf), however i cannot seem to understand what exactly i am doing wrong here.

Comment: For one thing, you have different values for the Content-Type header. Is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry, input error whilst creating the post.

Comment: I have two curl scripts, both are for different filetypes, both curl scripts work, however the python script won't post.

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what error you get from Python or what response you get from the server.

Comment: I just got a ton of errors that look to be connection related, no response.
Here is a link for a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0z26YKM2) file. As it won't all fit in a comment.

Comment: I notice that some of the errors look like they occur during SSL authentication. The -k flag in your curl command allows curl to use 'insecure' SSL connections. Do you know why the curl command uses that flag, or is this a command that you adapted from somewhere else?

Comment: The curl commands came from the SDK download.

Comment: Don't use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` with the requests headers. If you pass a file, requests knows its length and doesn't use chunked to send the file, so if you send such a header the server will expect chunked data but won't receive it. If you pass a generator or iterator without length as `data` then requests will use chunked automatically and add the required header. Don't add that header manually.

Comment: It seems when i removed that part of the headers, with no other changes, i get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed this line - `headers['Transfer-Encoding'] = 'chunked'`

Without any other changes i now seem to be getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that your connection seems to usually be reset when Requests is dealing with SSL, and the `-k` flag in your curl script which allows insecure SSL connections to be used (see [curl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)), it seems like there might be some issue with SSL authentication. You could try adding `verify=False` as an argument for your post request. If it works, then that's definitely what's causing this. Of course, doing this makes your connection insecure, so you would want to consider the security implications of that, depending on what you're using this for.

Comment: I tried adding verify=False, however still cannot seem to post data to the server. Thanks for trying to help resolve the issue nonetheless.